# How to set up a variable length array for a prime-sieve algorithm in C?

Tags: c, arrays, primes

I'm completely new to C, only really having had experience with Python in the past, so please forgive my ignorance here.

I'm trying to implement the prime-sieve algorithm of Eratosthenes in C. This algorithm recursively discards all multiples of a given number until the last number you wish to know is found. Specifically, the program will have an input **n**, and will output all prime numbers smaller than **n**.

To achieve this, I thought to create an array of length **n** and recursively cycle over this array, discarding integers I no longer care about (by changing them to 0).

The problem I found however, is that c does not allow for an array of variable length. I thought I outsmarted this rule for a little bit by doing this trick:

```
void Sieve(int n) {
    int prime[n+1];
}
```

But sadly, even variables given to functions aren't okay.

Hence my question: How can I initiate such an array in C?

Comment: Any C99 compliant compiler should support VLAs. (variable-length-arrays). Which compiler are you using?

Comment: Modern C allows variable length arrays, but apparenty your C compiler is older. Use dynamic memory allocation (`malloc` and friends), your C textbook contains all necessary information. But even with VLAs you'll run into problems for large values of `n` because on most implementation VLAs are allocated on the stack which has limited capacity (typically a few megabytes)

Comment: Like what **Jabberwoky** said, use `malloc`:  `int prime[] = malloc(sizeof(int) * (n + 1));`

Comment: @Tau, no it's `int *prime = malloc(...`, not `int prime[] = malloc(...`.

Comment: @Tau that's an invalid array initializer

Comment: @bool3max I'm using a recent version of gcc. I'm getting the error in visual studio, which I only use to write the code.

Comment: Ah, Visual Studio insists on using a C89 compiler.

Comment: Ah, apologies.  I had forgotten.

Comment: "How can I initiate such an array in C?" --> variable length arrays (VLA) cannot be _initialized_.  The elements  can be _assigned_ though.

Comment: @chux I understand you're trying to help my understanding of C, but like I said: I'm completely new to this language. Though you now taught me that there is a difference, I still wouldn't know what the difference would be. (I'm going to look this up, but in the future you might want to define your terms ^^)

Comment: look into *segmented* sieve of Eratosthenes. to get to a prime `p` you only need to know the primes up to its square root. also loops are better than recursion in C, AFAIK.

Comment: The C compiler of Visual Studio 2017 is ancient, most of it is from the early 1990s. Replace it with a modern C compiler.

Comment: When you compile with GCC, be sure to specify `-std=C99` or `-std=C11` (or `-std=C90`). Without this, GCC compiles GNU C, a language similar to but not the same as ISO Standard C. For useful diagnostics you should also use `-pedantic -Wall -Wextra`.

Comment: @MitchellFaas,  To help discern the difference in C terminology, some search links:  [initialize](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=x64&q=c++initialize&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) and [assign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_operator_(C%2B%2B)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dynamic memory allocation:

```
int* prime;
prime = malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
```

then use it as a regular array e.g. `prime[n-1]`

Comment: you may want to cast to int* the return value of the malloc: prime = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);

Comment: @AlexanderPane we do not [cast the result of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/1606345) in C

Comment: @KeineLust I agree with you. But doesn't casting increase the code portability and also gives the possibility to compile with a C++ compiler? But if this is not required, I agree that it is not useful

Comment: `prime = malloc(sizeof *prime * n);` has advantages of not having to code the type.

Comment: @AlexanderPane It is portable, because it is standard C and C is not C++. If you want to allocate something in C++, use new.

Comment: I would go with [`calloc`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/calloc) instead, because you need to initialize your members with 0 anyway. `prime = calloc(sizeof(*prime), n);`

Comment: @AlexanderPane: The cast is unnecessary, and just adds to the maintenance burden if you change the type of the target (say from `int` to `long`).  Actually, you can do it without exposing type at all - `prime = malloc( sizeof *prime * n );`.  I understand why people want to be able to compile the same source as C or C++, but honestly that's a mistake.  C and C++ have different rules, and programs that compile as both C and C++ may have subtly different behavior.  If you're writing C++, you shouldn't be using C-style memory management *at all* unless you really need to get your hands dirty.

Comment: @Hellow There is no need to initialize your members to 0. I initialize the entire array to its index instead since that seems to be the easiest for continued calculation.

Comment: @MitchellFaas You don't really need to store the numbers in the array itself. You only need to store a boolean flag to indicate whether the number has been sieved out yet. If you want to be really clever, you can pack several of those boolean flags into a single integer to save memory.